# How can I make a flame arrow set a block on fire?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image: an flaming arrow inside of wooden planks surrounded by iron]

The bow that shot it has the Flame enchantment. Why is that not enough to set block on fire?

**What can I do to actually set the block on fire with the arrow?**

Answer (score 4):

Per the [Minecraft Wiki's entry on enchanting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Flame):

> Unlike flint and steel, flaming arrows only affect players, mobs, and TNT. No other blocks catch fire, and they do not produce light. Fire damage applies after initial damage, similar to Fire Aspect.

---

Using [command blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block), however, you can *effectively* change this;

Looking at the commands in the video; here are the commands you'll need to put into the command blocks (arranged as shown in the video):

[image: visual of the command blocks]

```
/scoreboard objectives add Fire dummy
```

1. Creates the Fire objective that we'll need

   /fill ~ ~1 ~ ~9 ~1 ~ air
   /fill ~ ~1 ~ ~9 ~1 ~ redstone_block 0 destroy
   2&3. These two command blocks will create a super fast clock that will ensure that all the following commands work practically instantly.

   /scoreboard players set @a Fire 1 {SelectedItemSlot:0,Inventory:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:bow",tag:{ench:[{id:50,lvl:1}]}}]}
2. You'll need 9 of these, one for every action bar slot (0-8). This set's the player's 'Fire' score to 1 if they are holding a flame enchanted bow.

   /scoreboard players set @a Fire 0
3. You'll need 9 of these as well, sets the player's 'Fire' score back down to 0 when they are no longer actively holding a flame enchanted bow.

   /execute @a[score_Fire_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players set @e[type=Arrow,r=2] Fire 2
4. Whenever a player who's 'Fire' score is 1 fires an arrow, that arrow gains a 'Fire' score of 2.

   /execute @e[score_Fire_min=2] ~ ~ ~ /setblock ~ ~ ~ fire
5. Whenever an entity (the arrow shot from a flame enchanted bow) has a 'Fire' score of 2, wherever that entity is, this command creates a fire block that tracks the arrow. When the arrow lands on/next to a block, that space is also occupied by fire, which will spread to other burnable blocks.

Comment: I suppose that answers the question as posed. I guess what I meant to ask was "what can i do to change this?"

Comment: @DonielF Hmm... ok, that ***is*** possible with command blocks, but is considerably more complex. Give me a bit.

Comment: I believe they are working on an answer using command blocks, an alternative could be to use fire charges and have a trigger that you shoot instead.

Comment: @Codingale I wasn't sure if the Doniel's comment was because mine was initially incomplete (cat on arm caused me to hit enter early) and I had to edit it. But if you have another way to accomplish this, feel free to answer as well - my command block experience/knowledge is lacking, and I'm mostly transcribing a YouTube video.

Comment: Yep, just blame it on the cat. :) Yes, that's exactly what I was responding to. I've deleted my comment now that you've edited yours.

Comment: @Codingale How would you go about doing that?